# How to change databricks column type

Tags: python, sql, scala, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a csv in a blob storage and I was able to read it as a pandas datafrme in Databricks.

```
sourcefile = 'MiningProcess_Flotation_Plant_Database.csv'
df = spark.read.format('csv').option("header","true").load(db_ws.dp_engagement + '/' + sourcefile)
display(df)
```

I tried creating a table with this:

```
df.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable("MY_PERMANENT_TABLE_NAME")
```

And it works.

But alll columns which are numbers were created as strings.

So I tried to change the type:

```
%sql
ALTER TABLE MY_PERMANENT_TABLE_NAME CHANGE `% Iron Concentrate` TYPE decimal
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN is not supported for changing column '% Iron Concentrate' with type 'StringType' to '% Iron Concentrate' with type 'DecimalType(10,0)'
```

Dataset is here:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/sfbruno/mining-quality-xgboost/data

Comment: Are you sure that the datatype in the dataframe is actually numeric? Have you tried explicitly casting to the wanted datatype before writing to the table?

Comment: Yes, the dataset is here: https://www.kaggle.com/code/sfbruno/mining-quality-xgboost/data and how do I cast in code?

Comment: Instead of casting in sql, did you try cast in code directly ? like `df.withColumn("% Iron Concentrate", col("% Iron Concentrate").cast(DecimalType(38,18))).write....`

Answer (score 0):

You neither specify the schema of for your input data using `.schema` nor specify the `.option("inferSchema", "true")`, so CSV reader assumes that all columns are of the string type. If you don't want to specify schema, then add `.option("inferSchema", "true")` when reading data.

You can't simply change type using `ALTER TABLE`, especially for incompatible types, such as string to number.  So you either read data correctly & writing it using `.mode("overwrite")`, or doing `create table <table_name> as select cast(...) ... from <table_name>`...

Comment: I used this to load: df = spark.read.format('csv').option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").load(db_ws.dp_engagement + '/' + sourcefile)   and then df.dtypes and still all of them are string.

Comment: then you may have some wrong records, so it can't infer type. Try to specify schema explicitly

Comment: how is that done?

Comment: for example: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-csv-file-into-dataframe/